# searching by meta values showing inappropriate result

Tags: php, wordpress, search, custom-post-type

I am working on custom search by meta value and using this:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property_post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
                     'relation' => 'OR',
                     array(
                      'key' => 'custom_textarea',
                      'value' => 'me',  // if I use static keyword it works
                      'compare' => 'LIKE'
                      ),
                      array(
                      'key' => 'custom_price',
                      'value' => array( $_REQUEST['custom_price'], $_REQUEST['custom_price1'] ),
                      'type' => 'numeric',
                      'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                      ),
                      array(
                      'key' => 'custom_beds',
                      'value' => $_REQUEST['custom_beds'],
                      'compare' => '='
                      ),
                      array(
                      'key' => 'custom_bath',
                      'value' => $_REQUEST['custom_bath'],
                      'compare' => '='
                      ),
                      array(
                      'key' => 'custom_garage',
                      'value' => $_REQUEST['custom_garage'],
                      'compare' => '='
                      )
                      )

);
```

If I use some static keyword for meta value then it works but with the `$_REQUEST` it did not.
I checked `$_REQUEST` by `print_r($_REQUEST)`.

```
Array ( [custom_textarea] => aa[custom_price] => 1000 [custom_price1] => 4000[custom_beds] => 2[custom_garage] => 1)
```

So what should i do to make it fine.

Thanks in advance.........

Answer (score 0):

Store the $_REQUEST values to some variables and use it in the query

```
           $a=$_REQUEST['custom_price'];
```

and

```
        'value' => $a,
```

Comment: I have used like this in my programs.since you you are getting $_REQUEST values .it should work